# Updating DataFrame Column Conditionally Based on Another DataFrame Column Containing Lists

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

Say I have a DataFrame similar to this:

```
|---------------------|----------------------------------|
|         Cost        |               Combo              |
|---------------------|----------------------------------|
|          12         | ['apples', 'bananas', 'carrots'] |
|---------------------|----------------------------------|
|          7          |      ['apples', 'carrots']       |
|---------------------|----------------------------------|
```

If the 'Cost' column is a function of the cost of the individual 'Combo' items. The 'Combo' is a list of items. If a 'bananas' changes, then I want to modify the 'Cost' of any Combo with bananas accordingly.

While I can step through each row using iterrows, checking the Combo to see if bananas is in the Combo, I was wondering if there was a faster method I could use to achieve the same effect.

And what if I were to update more than one item in the combo, such as bananas and carrots?

Comment: Not really, since Pandas doesn't really work with Python structures in cells. Having a list in the cell removes most of your options beyond iteration.

Comment: Start by unnesting 'Combo' to simplify any further computations

Comment: unnest your column first , then update the value change the cost

Comment: So how would I go about unnesting Combo? The combinations are of varying lengths and could include hundreds if not thousands of items...